# How do I align equations on the left rather than the right?

Tags: math-mode, align

When I run the below code each line aligns on the right. How do I change this to align on the left instead please? I haven't gone into detail about what each equation represents as this is purely a formatting question and don't believe this to be necessary. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\V{V}

\begin{flalign} \V_{x}=v^{-1}v'd^\beta,\\
                           \V_{xx}=(-v^{-2}v'^2+v^{-1}v'')d^\beta,\\ 
                           \V_{xd}=v^{-1}v'\beta d^{\beta-1}, \\
                           \V_{d}=v\beta d^{\beta-1},\\
                           \V_{dd}=v\beta(\beta-1)d^{\beta-2} \end{flalign} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you rather align them at the `=`?

Comment: And alignment requires one or more `&` per line of which you use none. Might be an idea to read an intro to how to use the various alignment constructions. Here I agree with campa, much more readable if aligned on =

Comment: You may be under the impression that the "fl" part in "flalign" stands for "flush left". That's not the case, though; "fl" actually stands for "full length". Are you maybe thinking of the `fleqn` option of the `amsmath` package, where "fl" does stand for "flush left"?

Answer (score 7):

Forget `flalign`, which is for very specialized displays.

There are a few possibilities, two have been shown by [campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610423/4427), another one is with `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Some text before the display to show it in context.
Let's add some text in order to get a couple of lines.
\begin{alignat}{2}
& V_{x}  &&= v^{-1}v'd^\beta,\\
& V_{xx} &&= (-v^{-2}v'^2+v^{-1}v'')d^\beta,\\ 
& V_{xd} &&= v^{-1}v'\beta d^{\beta-1}, \\
& V_{d}  &&= v\beta d^{\beta-1},\\
& V_{dd} &&= v\beta(\beta-1)d^{\beta-2}
\end{alignat} 
Some text after the display to show it in context.
Let's add some text in order to get a couple of lines.

\end{document}
```

[image]